# Extract values if column contains keywords in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have one column in a data frame like this;

| A |
| --- |
| Apple banana cat |
| King blade night |
| Rose Dawn Jack |

I have two columns in other data frame like this;

| title | Key words |
| --- | --- |
| Happy | night |
| Sad | Dawn, Jack |
| Angry | Apple, BANANA |

I want to match column A with keywords ,if it contains any of keywords then I want to assign the appropriate title to a new column named as 'Group'. Do remembers the upper column is in different data frame than the lower one.

EDIT: Keywords are comma-separated and may contain both uppercase and lowercase values. in case of no match, column 'GROUP' should just give Nan.

Comment: How does 'Group' column look like? boolean values ?

Comment: You want to match each cell in column A with all cells in column Keywords, right?

Comment: Group column is empty, if any keyword matches with A then that cell of A will be assigned title in the column 'Group'.

Comment: Unclear what goes in column "Group". Add to question the column "Group", and show its content in at least these different inputs: **1)** `Dog` (not a keyword). **2)** `Apple` - shown as a keyword, but unclear whether must have both "Apple" and "Cat" to be `Angry`. **3)** `jack jill dawn` - does "Dawn Jack" have to be in exact order, or is this a match? **4)** `Apple banana cat` - this matches both "Happy" and "Angry"? What is the **exact** rule for deciding which wins? ...

Comment: ... **5)** Suppose there was another option `(title = "Frustrated", key_words = "Orange cat"`, and the input is `cat apple orange` - what is rule for deciding between `Angry` and `Frustrated`?

Comment: if there is even one word match then the title should be assigned in the column Group (for e. g if dawn matches then the group gets written SAD for column A's "Rose Dawn Jack").

Comment: Very sorry, that was my mistake to include same keywords for two different title. this is not the case for my data. I have edited the mistake. See if you can help me now .Thanks